# Ubunot Resize /var Directory

Tags: 20.04

hello my var directory is full and i want to add space to directory but i can't.
I have a lot of space in the /home and root directory and I want to give it to /var
I used GParted as a live CD but it did not allow me to increase or decrease and I do not know what to do and i'm not professional please help me

Comment: Post this: `sudo parted -l`. And `lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,LABEL,MOUNTPOINT,SIZE,fsused,MODEL | egrep -v "^loop"` New users do not need to have separate system partitions. May be required for servers or some special cases, sverage desktop user just needs / (root) & ESP if UEFI. The /home as a separate partition is suggested but not required. Often better to have /home as a partition when allocating lots of space to Linux. You can only modify partition from a live installer. You must have good backups as any interruption often corrupts system, then new install & restore from backups is only option.

Comment: It is unclear. Is `/var` located on a separate partition? Please add a screenshot of gparted.

Comment: Why would you have /var on its own partition? Besides that: clear log files in /var/log/ (on a desktop that is the only thing that gets large over time) and move databases and websites if you have those to a different disk.